# How do I plot an area chart in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to recreate [this visualization](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/E6PnybrWEAEJof9?format=jpg&name=large) using p5.js. I have some trouble understanding how to create the coordinates for the new points and plot them on my canvas.

The data is a series of negative-positive values that need to be plotted below and above an X-axis respectively (from left to right). This is a sample:

```
"character","roll_value"
"Daphne Blake",0
"Daphne Blake",-1
"Daphne Blake",-1
"Daphne Blake",-5
"Daphne Blake",-3
"Daphne Blake",2
```

So I know that I have to map the values between a certain negative and positive height so I've demarcated those heights as follows:

[image]

```
let maxNegativeHeight = sketch.height - 120;
let maxPositiveHeight = sketch.height/4;
```

For mapping the input I thought of creating a new function called `mapToGraph` which takes in the `roll_value`, the old X position, max height and min height. This would map the old values to a new incremented X position and a vertical height:

```js
 const mapToGraph = (value, oldXPos, maxHeight, minHeight) => {
    const newXPos = oldXPos + 10;
    const newYPos = sketch.map(value, 0, maxHeight, minHeight, maxHeight);
    return [newXPos, newYPos];
  };
```

In my draw function, I am drawing the points as follows:

```js
 sketch.draw = () => {
    for(let i = 0; i < data.getRowCount(); i++) {
      let character = data.getString(i, "character");
      if(character === 'Daphne Blake'){
        console.log(character);
        // Draw a horizontal line in the middle of the canvas
        sketch.stroke('#F18F01');
        sketch.line(0, sketch.height/2, sketch.width, sketch.height/2);
        // Plot the data points
        let value = data.getNum(i, "roll_value");
        let [newX, newY] = mapToGraph(value, 0, maxNegativeHeight, maxPositiveHeight);
        console.log(newX, newY);
        sketch.strokeWeight(0.5);
        sketch.point(newX, newY);
      }
    }
  };
```

However, this does not plot any points. My console.log shows me that I am not processing the numbers correctly, since all of them look like this:

```
10 -3
cardThree.js:46 Daphne Blake
cardThree.js:55 10 -4
cardThree.js:46 Daphne Blake
cardThree.js:55 10 -4
cardThree.js:46 Daphne Blake
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this and plot the points like the visualization I linked above?

Here is the full code of what I've tried [(live link to editor sketch)](https://editor.p5js.org/amanbhargava2001/sketches/BYovfsyAX).

[This is the full data](https://pastebin.com/uYPv9Vgf)

Answer (score 0):

In your code `newX` is always `10` since you always pass `0` as the second argument to `mapToGraph`. Additionally the vertical displacement is always very small and often negative. Since you are using `newY` directly rather than relative to the middle of the screen many of the points are off screen.